# Error running SharePoint 2010 Product Configuration Wizard after SP2 and July 2013 CU Update

Tags: 2010, configuration, configuration-wizard

I am having a problem upgrading my local SharePoint 2010 Development environment. I recently installed Service Pack 2 for SharePoint 2010 ([KB2687453](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2687453)) and the SharePoint 2010 Cumulative Update Package ([KB2817527](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2817527/en-us)). Upon successful completion of the two updates, I've tried running the SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration wizard multiple times.

The error I receive is:

> > Failed to initialize the upgrade sequence.
> >
> > An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown. Additional exception information: Exception of type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException" was thrown.

This wasn't too much to go on but I started Googling and looking around. I found a lot of articles telling me to check the SharePoint Health Analyzer for errors. I did and I found a long list of ***MissingWebPart***, ***MissingSetupFile*** and ***MissingFeature*** errors. I've worked several days on resolving all of these issues. They have all since been resolved. However I run the Configuration Wizard and it continues to return the same error.

I was wondering if anyone had any ideas?

I have a log file if anyone would like to view it. It's long though so it is not included in this post. I've sifted through it but not really found anything useful except:

> > Task upgradebootstrap has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
> >
> > Last message from task upgradebootstrap is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Upgrade.SPUpgradeException' was thrown.

Just as a reference, I'm running SharePoint 2010 on a Windows Server 2008 R2 environment.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I was missing this Microsoft Download, installed and voila!

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=122517

Comment: Thanks for the post. Unfortunately it did not work. I do appreciate your time though.

Comment: Did you uninstalled the Internet Infomation services from optionalfeatures, restarted and installed the whole branch of Internet information services from optional features again?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the upgrade log a little more closely, I found this error.

Upgrade Timer job is exiting due to exception: System.ArgumentException: localStoragePath

Right before that line, it was working on the search DB, so I ended up finding this article and removed the SSA, and then the upgrade worked great.

http://blog.bugrapostaci.com/tag/localstoragepath/

Comment: Donot post your request/questions in answer section. please follow as mentioned in the below URL http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).